# Online-model libraries for R

Tags: library, statistics, r

"Online" models are those where you train a model and then update the coefficients/weights of the model as new data comes in. This avoids needing to load and process all data every time you want to update the model. A popular example is content recommendation engines, such as Netflix's recommender.

I know how to do this in Python and MATLAB, but I've been unsuccessfully looking for R libraries ("packages") to enable me to do this in R.